# ojAlgo - Multiply 2x2 matrix by 1x1 vector?

Tags: ojalgo

I'm new to ojAlgo. What is the best way to multiply a 2x2 matrix by a 2x1 vector?  Can I use the PrimitiveMatrix class or does this require using Arrays?  Please provide an example.

Comment: What have you tried, and what was the problem? You may want to read this: https://www.ojalgo.org/2019/03/linear-algebra-introduction/

Comment: I did read the introduction, but I was unsure and was looking for a simple example.

Comment: There is example code on that page.

Comment: No examples of Matrix x Vector on the page, however. I guess you could always store vectors as 1-column matrices. @rclang did you ever figure out how to do this?